# Black screen blinking cursor Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 22.04

Basically I would find myself working on my Lenovo laptop (I completely deleted Windows 10 since it wouldn't allow me running both Windows and Linux Ubuntu) and Linux just launching the boot where your screen is black with the white blinking cursor and then I have to force shut down my laptop in order for it to stop. Is there any reason why this happens and how it can be fixed?

Comment: One likely cause: `grub` installation messed up e.g. by Windows update. Possible remedy: google `reinstall grub` - find instructions how to do it, then boot your installation media in "Try Ubuntu"-mode where you should be able to follow the instructions.